# How do I make a triangle of numbers using python loops?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to achieve this

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
        0 1 2 3 4 5
          0 1 2 3 4
            0 1 2 3
              0 1 2
                0 1
                  0
```

And I'm getting close but now I'm stuck. Here is my current code

```
def triangle():
    n = 9
    numList = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    for i in range(10):
        for i in numList:
            print(i, end="  ")
        print()
        numList[n] = 0
        n -= 1
triangle()
```

And this is the current output

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  0  
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  0  0  
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  0  0  0  
0  1  2  3  4  5  0  0  0  0  
0  1  2  3  4  0  0  0  0  0  
0  1  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  1  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

So I'm there in a round about way, except, its backwards, and there is 0's instead of spaces

Comment: For starters, can you not work out where the extra `0`s come from and do something about it? `numList[n] = 0` --> `numList.pop()` for example.

Comment: Sorry kaylum, I'm still learning basics and completely forgot about the .pop() function, this will make it a lot easier, now I can just figure out how to 'reverse' it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interesting puzzle, you could try this:

```
n = range(0,10)    #set your range
while len(n)<20:   #loop until it exhausts where you want it too
  print ''.join(str(e) for e in n[0:10])  #print as a string!
  n = [' ']+n      #prepend blank spaces
```

[here is an example](http://rextester.com/DTSBRB59410)

You could apply the same logic to your attempt.  Basically I add a space to the beggining of N after each loop and then print only the first ten elements.  The way I print the list is a little clunky because I am joining, I need to change each element to a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```
def triangle():
    for i in range(10):
        print i * "  ",
        for j in range(10 - i):
            print j,
        print    

triangle()
```

The code is almost self explaining.

Online example is [here](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_988HYxG9MG_1.py)

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions are fine, but life becomes a little easier with `numpy`'s `arange` and the overloaded `*` operator for strings. Python's built-ins are very powerful.

```
for i in range(11):
    print ' ' * i + ''.join(str(elt) for elt in np.arange(10 - i))
```